# Using reshape2 to pivot data by creating a column from multiple factors

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following Data:

```
ID  Device  TIME    New 
ABC Brush   2016_Q1 3   
ABC Brush   2016_Q2 4   
ABC Brush   2016_Q3 2   
ABC Brush   2016_Q4 1   
DEF Brush   2016_Q1 4   
DEF Brush   2016_Q2 3   
DEF Brush   2016_Q3 5   
DEF Brush   2016_Q4 2   
ABC Pen     2016_Q1 1   
ABC Pen     2016_Q2 3   
ABC Pen     2016_Q3 2   
ABC Pen     2016_Q4 4   
DEF Pen     2016_Q1 1   
DEF Pen     2016_Q2 3   
DEF Pen     2016_Q3 2
```

I want to create a new dataset where there exists one record for each id like this

```
    Id  brush_New_2016_Q1   brush_New_2016_Q2   brush_New_2016_Q3   brush_New_2016_Q4   pen_New_2016_Q1 pen_New_2016_Q2 pen_New_2016_Q3 pen_New_2016_Q4
ABC     3                       4                   2                       1                   1               3               2               4
DEF     4                       3                   5                       2                   1               3               2               0
```

I know for a fact that I have to use `Reshape2` package but I am unsure how to use it to generate the result table. Is here  way to automate the column name creation? I have 20 devices and 3 years worth data.

Comment: `reshape2:: dcast(dat,ID~Device+TIME,fill=0,value.var = "New")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reshape2, but I find I have a much easier time using [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/).

`df %>% 
  unite(new_col, 2, 3, sep = "_") %>% 
  spread(new_col, New)`

`unite()` creates a new column by gluing together the `Device` and `TIME` columns, and names it `new_col`, and then `spread()` casts the values of that `new_col` along the top as columns, using `New` as the key.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dcast` function from `data.table` package:

```
# create a dummy column
df$sudo <- paste(df$Device, 'New', df$TIME, sep = '_')

# expand the data using dcast
dcast(df[c('ID','sudo','New')], ID ~ sudo, fill = 0)
```